# Jquery selector to select elements without specified text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Simple question.

I want to create a jquery selector to select all `<p>` tags which does not have the text equal to `foo`.

The more elegant the better!

The first bit is trivial: `$('p')`

Thanks!

Comment: 'foo' is separated word, or can be inside word, too, like 'foobar'?

Comment: No must equal exactly! No more. No less

Comment: And there can be more words, right? But if one of words is 'foo' - p should not be selected?

Comment: No. It has to be foo exactly! Not " hello foo bar". If its foo exactly don't select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    if($(this).text()!=='foo')
    return $(this);
  }).css('color','red'); // for demo purposes
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qye9by2y/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$( "p:not(:contains('Foo'))" )
```

> Select all elements that contain the specified text.
>   [DOCUMENTATION](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

`UPDATE`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8rvy8Lmb/)

For exact match you can use `.filter()` to select only the same exact match

Answer (score 1):

you could make a separate function that can `addClass('notfoo')` to the paragraphs that don't have "foo" in them, then select all paragraphs with class `'notfoo'`

Answer (score 0):

<del>You can use this to select element that not contain specific text.</del>

<del>$("p:not([value='foo']")</del>

Comment: This will also exclude `food`. He said it should be an exact match.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, Sorry for my mistaken.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. It could works for inputs (which has value attribute), afaik...